# Simple product with attributes(Color and Size)

Tags: attributes, simple-product

Can we make a **simple product** with attributes(Colors and size) for rental product cause I want to show attributes in simple product?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use the one colour and one size attribute with simple product. If you want variations of colour and size then you can use configurable type of products.

Comment: Yes I want a variety of color and size but in the simple product PDP page instead of configurable PDP page, how can  do this?